# iOS Swift - UIScrollView make current page view bigger

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to build a paging scroll view that the middle (selected view) animates to appear bigger then the options of the left and right. See screenshot below for what I am referring to:

[image]

Looking for assistance on how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel. It's what you want ;)

> iCarousel is a class designed to simplify the implementation of various types of carousel (paged, scrolling views) on iPhone, iPad and Mac OS. iCarousel implements a number of common effects such as cylindrical, flat and "CoverFlow" style carousels, as well as providing hooks to implement your own bespoke effects. Unlike many other "CoverFlow" libraries, iCarousel can work with any kind of view, not just images, so it is ideal for presenting paged data in a fluid and impressive way in your app. It also makes it extremely easy to swap between different carousel effects with minimal code changes.